# Android failed to find build tools

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native, gradlew

I'm getting the following error trying to run my react native app on an android simulator. I can verify `$android_home` and have installed sdk v23 with the sdk manager tool.

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME                              
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk

$ react-native run-android --stacktrace --info 
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --stacktrace --info)...
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/harrymoreno/programming/contactsPro/android/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/harrymoreno/programming/contactsPro/android/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'contactsPro', project ':app']
Evaluating root project 'contactsPro' using build file '/Users/harrymoreno/programming/contactsPro/android/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':app' using build file '/Users/harrymoreno/programming/contactsPro/android/app/build.gradle'.
Creating configuration compile.
Creating configuration apk.
Creating configuration provided.
Creating configuration wearApp.
Creating configuration androidTestCompile.
Creating configuration androidTestApk.
Creating configuration androidTestProvided.
Creating configuration androidTestWearApp.
Creating configuration testCompile.
Creating configuration testApk.
Creating configuration testProvided.
Creating configuration testWearApp.
Creating configuration debugCompile.
Creating configuration debugApk.
Creating configuration debugProvided.
Creating configuration debugWearApp.
Creating configuration testDebugCompile.
Creating configuration testDebugApk.
Creating configuration testDebugProvided.
Creating configuration testDebugWearApp.
Creating configuration releaseCompile.
Creating configuration releaseApk.
Creating configuration releaseProvided.
Creating configuration releaseWearApp.
Creating configuration testReleaseCompile.
Creating configuration testReleaseApk.
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided.
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:89)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.groovy:507)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:455)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:414)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 33 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.529 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
Could not install the app on the device, see the error above.
```

Comment: Which version of **Build Tools** actually resides in your ANDROID_SDK home directory?